# Idiom suggestions for 'made an impact'

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

This is question is related to an English work I am currently doing. I have a phrase where I want to describe how a particular person has 'made a considerable impact' on the world that we live in today.

This is the sentence I am using:

> Franco Zeffirelli made considerable impact on the world of film following his release of 'Romeo and Juliet'.

The types of answers needed:

- idioms
- short phrases

What types of answers won't be needed:

- idioms/phrases limited local (or regional) uses

Ideas I have had:

- 'considerable impact'
- 'profound impact'

I was wanting to use an idiom or some sort of phrase for this. Can I please have some suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the idiomatic expression,

***[leave (one's) mark](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/leave+(one%27s)+mark):***

> To do something that will be remembered or that makes one famous or successful; to do something that is very important or meaningful.

> - The actress first left her mark with her incredible performance as Lady Macbeth on Broadway.

(The Free Dictionary)

So you could say:

- Franco Zeffirelli left his mark on the movie industry following his release of 'Romeo and Juliet'

Answer (score 2):

For a very large impact, a paradigm shift, the term **quantum shift** would be appropriate.

- With his movie 'Romeo and Juliet', Franco Zeffirelli brought about a quantum shift in the world of film.

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quantum) defines the related terms **quantum leap / quantum jump**:

> A quantum leap or quantum jump in something is a very great and sudden
> increase in its size, amount, or quality.
>
> - *The vaccine represents a quantum leap in healthcare*.

An example from [ReversoContext](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/has+brought+about+a+shift) is

> *The revolution in digital technology has brought about a quantum shift*
> *in the way we communicate with one another.*

Comment: Ironically, in physics, an actual quantum shift is the *smallest* possible change in matter!

Comment: The important part of a quantum shift is the non-continuous nature of the change. There is not a continuous curve from one state to another but rather a sudden jump between two states. Winning the lottery is a quantum shift, saving up over a decade is not.

Answer (score 2):

[Made an impression](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Made+an+impression)

> To have or create a strong impact on someone, whether good or bad (usually specified by an adjective before "impression.")

Franco Zeffirelli made a lasting impression on the world of film following his release of 'Romeo and Juliet'.

Another phrase is *Lasting impact* which seems to be used in similar context as [Google Ngram's books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lasting%20impact%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en) suggest

> Franco Zeffirelli's  'Romeo and Juliet' left a lasting impact on the world of film.

Comment: *enduring influence* is another alternative, but I am not sure it is a phrase

Answer (score 0):

How bout **transformed**? From Lexico:

> **[transform](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transform)**: Make a marked change in the form, nature, or appearance of.

Your example:

> Franco Zeffirelli **transformed** the world of film following his release of 'Romeo and Juliet'.

Another possibility is *[revolutionized](https://www.lexico.com/definition/revolutionize)*, but I think that would overstate Zeffirelli's impact.